# new cPanel user can't login to cPannel nor ssh

Tags: cpanel, users

I'm running a webserver with CloudLinux installed on it. To make the server management a little easier, we've also installed cPanel on it. With the root account, accessing cPanel works. Connecting to the server, using the root account via ssh works.

I've then created a new user, let's call that user `alice`, using cPanel and made checks at `CGI Privilege` and `Shell Access`. I didn't activate the `Reseller Privileges`.
Unfortunately, this new user can't login to cPannel (to select for example, what PHP version should be running), nor to ssh using `ssh alice@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

When I login to the server, using my root account, I see, that cPanel created a folder `/home/alice/` containing amongst others a `public_html` folder and so on, so it seams to have worked.

Are there other settings I need to enable in order to grant this user access to cPanel and ssh?

Comment: I found this [tutorial for adding users via cPanel](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/cpanel/how-to-create-additional-users-via-cpanel).  It looks like you hit all the basics.  For SSH, the user may need to generate keys [like this](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_cpanel.htm) however that requires that they log into their cPanel account first and go to the advanced section.

Comment: In the end, it was all my fault. I've managed to screw up the resources for new users, which meant instead of 0.5 GB, the account got 0.5 MB RAM assigned >.<

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate that you found the problem.  It was a mistake that is unlikely to address similar problems by other people searching for this question.

Comment: absolutely. It was all my error, so feel free to close it.